# Maximal flow graph algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, max-flow

**Does someone know which algorithm should be used to find the maximal flow in the *unoriented* graph?**

As far as I understand, the unoriented network here basically turns the graph into a multigraph with vertices connected by two *"ordinary"* ribs and two *"fake"* ribs, which are, for example used in the `Ford-Fulkerson` algorithm.

But how should I handle the case of a multigraph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have unoriented edge

```
     5
* ------ *
```

then you can turn it into two oriented edges:

```
     5
  ------>
*         *
  <------
     5
```

Ford-Fulkerson method works on such graphs perfectly.